# Extracting certain date and time using regex

Tags: python, regex

Regex expression tested using http://pythex.org/

> Expression:
>   (\d{2})/.-/.-\s([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$

I only want to be able to print out 30/06/2016 17:15 as two individual variable.
The above cant work! can anybody enlighten me on my expression? It seems to be matching "30/06/2016 17:15" exactly only

Answer (score 0):

It works fine using a combination of `ast.literal_eval` and `re`:

`ast.literal_eval` gets rid of the `tuple`-like structure for you. The rest is a piece of cake.

This solution is more robust than regex-only solutions:

```
import ast,re

a = "('=====================================', '30/06/2016 17:15 T001 201603301', 'ORDER: C002946', 'Cashier: 001', '--------------------------------------')"

t=ast.literal_eval(a)

z=re.compile(r"(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d)\s(\d\d:\d\d)")

m = z.match(t[1])

if m:
    print("date: {}, time {}".format(m.group(1),m.group(2)))
```

Result:

```
date: 30/06/2016, time 17:15
```

Remarks:

- The regex is not optimal, but that's not the hardest part once the tuple is read and parsed.
- Maybe it would be even better to get a real `time` structure using `time.strptime` (no need for regex in that case).

Comment: YOU FOR PRESIDENT! THUMBS UP MAN

Comment: How do i separate the print `print(z.match(t[1]).group(1))` into two print statement?